# EF Core: Detached lazy-loading navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-2.2

I have the following query:

```
        var query = _context.QuestOrders.Include(a => a.Driver).ThenInclude(i => i.DlStateProvince)
            .Where(p => carrierIds.Contains(p.Driver.CarrierId))
            ....
            ;
```

and then try to call the following:

```
        var queryDto = query.AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<DcReportDonorResultDto>(_mapperConfiguration);
        var reports = new PagedList<DcReportDonorResultDto>(queryDto, pageIndex, pageSize);
```

where `DcReportDonorResultDto` has a property:

```
public string PrimaryId { get; set; }
```

which mapped the following:

```
        CreateMap<QuestOrder, DcReportDonorResultDto>()
            .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.PrimaryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Driver.PrimaryId))
```

and `PrimaryId` is defined in `QuestOrder` as:

```
    public string PrimaryId
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DlNumber) && DlStateProvinceId.HasValue)
                return DlStateProvince.Abbreviation + DlNumber.Replace("-", "");
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I received the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'DlStateProvince'
>   on detached entity of type ''. Lazy-loading is not supported for
>   detached entities or entities that are loaded with 'AsNoTracking()'.'.
>   This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID
>   'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings'
>   method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.'

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the **computed** `QuestOrder.PrimaryId` property.

When used in LINQ to Entities queries, such properties cannot be translated to SQL and require client evaluation. And even when supported, client evaluation does not play well when accessing navigation properties inside - both eager or lazy loading do not function properly and lead to either runtime exceptions or wrong return value.

So the best is to make them translatable, which requires dealing with translatable **expressions**.

In all the cases, start by converting the computed property body from block to conditional operator (to make it translatable):

```
public string PrimaryId =>
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.DlNumber) && this.DlStateProvinceId.HasValue) ?
    this.DlStateProvince.Abbreviation + this.DlNumber.Replace("-", "") :
    string.Empty;
```

Now, short turn, quick-and-dirty solution is to extract the actual expression for the computed property, copy/paste it in the mapping and replace `this` with `src.Driver`:

```
.ForMember(dst => dst.PrimaryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
    //src.Driver.PrimaryId
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.Driver.DlNumber) && src.Driver.DlStateProvinceId.HasValue) ?
    src.Driver.DlStateProvince.Abbreviation + src.Driver.DlNumber.Replace("-", "") :
    string.Empty
))
```

Long term, or if you have many properties like this, or you need to use it in other mappings/queries, or just because of the code duplication, this is not a good solution. You need a way to replace the computed property accessor inside query expression tree with the corresponding expression extracted from the body.

Neither C#, nor BCL or EF Core help in that regard. Several 3rd party packages are trying to address this problem to some sort of degree - [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), [NeinLinq](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq) etc., but there is a little not very well known gem called [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) which does that with minimum code changes.

All you need is to install the [DelegateDecompiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DelegateDecompiler) or [DelegateDecompiler.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DelegateDecompiler.EntityFrameworkCore) package, mark your computed properties with `[Computed]` attribute

```
[Computed] // <--
public string PrimaryId =>
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.DlNumber) && this.DlStateProvinceId.HasValue) ?
    this.DlStateProvince.Abbreviation + this.DlNumber.Replace("-", "") :
    string.Empty;
```

and then call `Decompile` (or `DecompileAsync`) on the top level queryable

```
var queryDto = query.AsNoTracking()
    .ProjectTo<DcReportDonorResultDto>(_mapperConfiguration)
    .Decompile(); // <--
```

No special mappings are needed for AutoMapper, e.g. you can keep the usual

```
.ForMember(dst => dst.PrimaryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Driver.PrimaryId)
```

For AutoMapper projection queries (produced with `ProjectTo`) you can even eliminate the need for calling `Decompile` / `DecompileAsync` by providing the following little `"bridge" between the two libraries:

```
namespace AutoMapper
{
    using DelegateDecompiler;
    using QueryableExtensions;

    public static class AutoMapperExtensions
    {
        public static IMapperConfigurationExpression UseDecompiler(this IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
        {
            var resultConverters = config.Advanced.QueryableResultConverters;
            for (int i = 0; i < resultConverters.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!(resultConverters[i] is ExpressionResultDecompiler))
                    resultConverters[i] = new ExpressionResultDecompiler(resultConverters[i]);
            }
            return config;
        }

        class ExpressionResultDecompiler : IExpressionResultConverter
        {
            IExpressionResultConverter baseConverter;
            public ExpressionResultDecompiler(IExpressionResultConverter baseConverter) => this.baseConverter = baseConverter;
            public bool CanGetExpressionResolutionResult(ExpressionResolutionResult expressionResolutionResult, PropertyMap propertyMap) => baseConverter.CanGetExpressionResolutionResult(expressionResolutionResult, propertyMap);
            public bool CanGetExpressionResolutionResult(ExpressionResolutionResult expressionResolutionResult, ConstructorParameterMap propertyMap) => baseConverter.CanGetExpressionResolutionResult(expressionResolutionResult, propertyMap);
            public ExpressionResolutionResult GetExpressionResolutionResult(ExpressionResolutionResult expressionResolutionResult, PropertyMap propertyMap, LetPropertyMaps letPropertyMaps) => Decompile(baseConverter.GetExpressionResolutionResult(expressionResolutionResult, propertyMap, letPropertyMaps));
            public ExpressionResolutionResult GetExpressionResolutionResult(ExpressionResolutionResult expressionResolutionResult, ConstructorParameterMap propertyMap) => Decompile(baseConverter.GetExpressionResolutionResult(expressionResolutionResult, propertyMap));
            static ExpressionResolutionResult Decompile(ExpressionResolutionResult result)
            {
                var decompiled = DecompileExpressionVisitor.Decompile(result.ResolutionExpression);
                if (decompiled != result.ResolutionExpression)
                    result = new ExpressionResolutionResult(decompiled, result.Type);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and just call `UseDecompiler()` during AutoMapper initialization, for instance

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.UseDecompiler(); // <--
    // the rest (add profiles, create maps etc.) ...
});
```

Comment: this is fascinating!!! I've been struggling to strike the right balance between query response size and response content. Navigation properties in EF Core in particular are giving me headaches. Being able to query on computed properties might be essential to my final strategy. Thank you so much for sharing this.